# Auditing Changes in Entity JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have Spring MVC + JPA applications.

I have several entities in application which Are constantly changing. I want to be able to audit this changes. I found that there is an `@Audited` annotation that track changes to certain fields or whole Entity. I want to know if there any way to configure this track options - I want to be able to track what was changed and who changed it.Also is it possible to have changes from several Entities in 1 Table in SQL? Also is it possible to track changes of - `@OneToMany` Fields in Entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can keep track the changes made, updated user and time-stamp.

Hibernate provides `@Audited` annotation to maintain entity version.

Spring provides `@CreatedBy` `@LastModifiedBy` `@CreatedDate` and       `@LastModifiedDate` annotations, among these you need to provide the user name who updates using `AuditorAware` bean.

To enable auditing,

1. should add `@EnableJpaAuditing` on configuration class
2. `@Audited` and `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` on entities
3. `AuditorAware<T>` to provide the username
4. Children entities should be annotated with `@Audited`

Example

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> createAuditorProvider() {
    return () -> "username"; // should be from context/session
}
```

For each entities an additional table will be created to maintain version

1. `{ENTITY_NAME}_AUD` // can override the prefix and suffix of audit table name
2. `REVINFO`

below is an example of one-to-many relationship with hibernate and spring auditing

UserInfo.java

```
@Audited
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class UserInfo extends AuditInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserAddress> addresses;

}
```

UserAddress.java

```
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class UserAddress extends AuditInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long addressId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Column
    private Long no;

    @Column
    private String street;

}
```

AuditInfo.java

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditInfo {

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

}
```

Comment: can I use Hibernate JPA and Spring data JPA same time? I can't make @EnableJpaAuditing recognised. what library I need to import for this?

Comment: `spring-data-jpa`, `hibernate-jpa` and `hibernate-envers`

Comment: Hi I am quite late, can I ask how these tables are created ?

Comment: @Vipul if its a spring boot project you can use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to create tables

Comment: this is a terrible example. this is for versioning not auditing what the OP asked