# Hibernate Interceptor fetching foreign keys issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement an audit through an interceptor.The problem kicks in when i try to get the change in a foreign key attribute.It fetches the change as

> data.model.foo to data.model.foobar

What i need though is the  get the change in values of that table.
For example if i change a ***city*** of a ***student*** from ***abc*** to ***xyz*** which is a foreign key in the student class under field ***name***. i want to get the change as same but interceptor fetches it as an object.

Can you please derive a generic function to fetch the change as text.  (Prefer this approach)

> or

Can you help me in getting the change in value of the foreign key object if i know the class or the field which is changed.

Comment: You can use cascade wen update. see this https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: See my answer to intercept and audit changes in Hibernate http://stackoverflow.com/a/38162978/3344829

Comment: could you post your code here? I suppose you are looking for some similar:
{code}    private Object retrieveIdFromEntity(Object entity) {
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
      return ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier();
    }
    return retrieveIdWithReflection(entity);
  }
{code}